# Speed difference betwen subprocess.call() and os.system()

Tags: python, performance, operating-system, subprocess

Is there any speed difference in the execution of the `subprocess.call()` and `os.system()` command? Suppose that the command itself is exactly same.

I know there are many posts out there talking about the benefits of subprocess and why `os.system()` should be ditched...but no one mentioned anything about the speed of them. From what I understand, subprocess is nowhere near a wrapper for `os.system()`, which means there could be speed differences.

Would prefer an answer with experimental data instead of theory stuff, as I'm actually needing it to evaluate the performance of a script that has hundreds of such calls.

Comment: What is the execution time taken by what is called through subprocess or os.system ? Because if it's large enough, it becomes negligible in front of any overhead introduced by subprocess

Comment: Well it varies...some takes a few minutes, some between 10 to 100ms. Anyways, because the application I'm developing has strict requirements for execution time, so I just wanted to know how much time I could save or waste by using either option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`os.system` is significantly more expensive than `subprocess.call` on Windows. Indeed, `os.system` starts a batch interpreter that will parse the command, then typically locate an executable to run in the path and then start a new process running the target executable. Meanwhile, `subprocess.call` mainly starts the target executable. Running a new process is one of the most expensive operation so running two processes makes the operation much slower.

A simple benchmark on Windows proves this (calling `ls.exe` on an empty directory):

```
os.system:       62.3 ms/call
subprocess.call: 34.8 ms/call
```

On Linux/Mac/WSL, the cost of starting a new process is much smaller. Thus, we should expect the gap to be smaller which is the case. However, the results are a bit surprising as `subprocess.call` is a bit slower. Here is the result on WSL2:

```
os.system:       3.0 ms/call
subprocess.call: 3.8 ms/call
```

Comment: very helpful and interesting findings. Thank you!

Comment: I get 3.2 ms for `os.system`, 4.5 ms for `subprocess.call(shell=True)`, and 1.1 ms without `shell=True` on a native Ubuntu machine.  Using `/bin/true` reduces the time by about a quarter in all cases.